# Delete subdirectory/file from WebDav server

Tags: curl, webdav

I am trying to delete a file in the web dav server. Below is the test directory structure.

```
<dav url>/test/sampledir/test1.txt
<dav url>/test/sampledir/test2.txt
```

Here is my command:

```
curl -u testuser:testpwd -X DELETE <dav url>/test/sampledir/test1.txt
```

However, when I execute the code the "test" directory is deleted. Am I missing something in my command?

Comment: Is that the real path? Or does the real path have spaces in it?

Comment: Definitely some folder has a space. Then you need to enclose url in quotes e.g. `curl -u user:pwd -X DELETE 'http://example.com/sample dir/test1.txt'`. See examples https://gist.github.com/stokito/cf82ce965718ce87f36b78f7501d7940

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This answer is **wrong** as per Evert's comment below. I choose to leave it in case anyone misunderstands the documentation as I did.

---

Have you tried setting the `If-Match` header, as in the [SabreDAV documentation](https://sabre.io/dav/davclient/)?

For instance:

```bash
curl -u testuser -XDELETE -H "If-Match: 'test1'" <dav url>/test/sampledir/test1.txt
```

Comment: I wrote that page, but no ETags / If-Match is not for specifying filenames.